# How to change d3 tooltip background color when mouseover dot?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I need to change the tooltip background color when i mouseover the dot which is follow the color of dot. for example here, the background keep "lightsteeblue".

my dot color code is this:

```
.style("fill", function (d) { return myColor(d.HillName); })
```

my tooltip class:

```
div.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    min-width: 80px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    font: 16px tahoma;
    background: lightsteelblue;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

this is my color range for data:

```
var myColor = d3.scaleOrdinal()
            .range(d3.schemeCategory10);
```

this is where mouseover code:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d){
                div.transition()
                .duration(200)
                .style("opacity", 0.9);
                div.html("<b>Hill name:</b> " + d.HillName + "<br>" + "Latitude:" + d.Latitude + "°     " + "Longitude:" + d.Longitude + "°<br>" + "Osgrid:" + d.Osgrid + "<br>" + "Height:" + d.Height)
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-28) + "px")    
            })
 .on("mouseout", function(d){
                div.transition()
                .duration(500)
                .style("opacity", 0);
            });
```

Comment: Try `div.style("background", myColor(d.HillName));`. Also, please turn this into a runnable [mre], with some sample data, so we can see what you mean. See also [ask]

Comment: yeah its work!. thanks for the help